# Is it possible to programmatically check if any file explorer is present on my Android device?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to import a file into my application, below is the code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");              
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                    REQUESTCODE);
```

What i want is that before firing the intent i want to programatically check whether any File explorer is present on my device or not? If yes then fire the intent but if no then i want to redirect user to Play store to download one, as it is mandatory for selecting a file. Is this feature possible to implement? Kindly enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just add the functionality to browse the filesystem to your own app? It's not difficult. What if the user doesn't want to install a 3rd party File Explorer app on their device?

Comment: @Squonk Million dollar question, that functionality is already implemented but the project requirement is different. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the file explorer is present or not using the below code, If not then ask user to download the app.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("file/*");
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                                PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES));

if (list.size > 0) {
    // File explore is present (Size tells how many file explorers are present)
} else {

    // Not present
    // Just pointing to this app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm
    // You can choose whichever you need

     try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm")));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm")));
      }
    }
```

Comment: My freind this doen't work in my case, I want to browse my local storage of the device for which i require ES file explorer or something of that kind. In your code list.size() is always > 0 hence always true, hence the popup that i get gives me Google drive and drop box as options which is of no use to me, can i explicitly find file explorer like ES on the device?

Comment: See my edit, It will first check if the file explorer is present. If not then ask user to download the app which I pointed. Is this what you need?